# Populate List of Checkboxes using Radio Button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I'm attempting to populate a group of report_id's in the following checkboxes created by the following for loop by clicking a radio button.

```
<div class="col"><h4 style="margin-top: 0"><strong>Application Suite</strong></h4><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="suite" value="1" onclick="CheckBoxes">>Executive CFO Suite</div>
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% if fingrouplist is not None %}
                      <h4><strong>Financial</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="togglerep(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                              <ul>
                              {% for app in fingrouplist %}
                              <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                              {% endfor %}
                              </ul>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
```

To do this I'm using the following OnClick javascript function which i'm a complete beginner.  I've tried the following with no luck:

```
function CheckBoxes(selection) {
  if (selection == 1) {
    $('#Report_Id').prop('checked', true) == '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '22', '23', '26', '28', '29', '30', '31', '33','34', '35', '36', '39', '40', '47', '48', '50', '52', '59', '60';
  }
}
```

Sometimes the list of report_id won't always included every option, but i only want to include the options that exists with the users settings in their report_id derived from the for loop.

I also have a python object created that defines the list of reports, so if i can get it from that option instead of typing the list of numbers it may be a better route to go.

```
rolebased = QvReportList.objects.filter(role_based_id__exact = '1').values('report_id', 'report_name_sc').distinct()
```

Any help to get me going in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Get all the checked checkboxes values?

Comment: I'm trying to check those report id's in the form when the radio button is clicked.  I'm not sure what to search because i can't find a simple example of this.

Comment: Let me see if i get it, when you click the radiobutton, you need to check some of the checkboxes, am i right?

Comment: Have you tried to add all id's of checkboxes?  `$('#checkbox_id_1, #checkbox_id_2,  #checkbox_id_3, ...., #checkbox_id_60').prop('checked', true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors in your code. In first place, you should use `()` to invoke a function and not just its name, so you would need to change the radio button like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="suite" value="1" onclick="CheckBoxes(this)">
```

Then you will need to modify the function code to get all the values of the checked ckeckboxes;

```
function CheckBoxes(clicked) {

    // array of checkboxes to check
    var checked = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 39, 40, 47, 48, 50, 52, 59, 60];

    // if the radio button is checked
    if($(clicked).is(':checked')) {

        // for each checked checkbox
        $('input[name*="report_id"]').each(function() {

            // set as checked if the value is defined in the array
            // Convert $(this).val() to Numnber() to compare against a number
            $(this).prop('checked', checked.indexOf(Number($(this).val())) >= 0);

        });

    }

}
```

As a side note, if you are going to submit a form with multiple checkboxes with the same name, you should use the array name definition `[]`. In your case it will be (note the use of the square brackets in the name definition):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="report_id[]" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >
```

Check my working snippet:

```js
function CheckBoxes(clicked) {
  
  // Array of checked values
  var checked = [1, 2, 5];
  
  // if the radio button is checked
  if($(clicked).is(':checked')) {
  
    // for each checked checkbox
    $('input[name*="report_id"]').each(function() {
    
      // set as checked if the value is defined in the array
      // Convert $(this).val() to Numnber() to compare against a number
      $(this).prop('checked', checked.indexOf(Number($(this).val())) >= 0);
    
    });
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" onclick="CheckBoxes(this)">
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="report_id[]"> Value 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="report_id[]"> Value 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="report_id[]"> Value 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="report_id[]"> Value 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="report_id[]"> Value 5</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance muecas.